# python xml change tags value if they have spec child

Tags: python, xml

I have 50MB xml file and i would like change specyfic tags value when they have child tag with specyfic value by python. I tried to used xml.etree.ElementTree and any stockoverflow users advices but i'm still don't have results. Can you give me some hints?

```
<parent>
  <child1>321</child1>
  <par_child2>
    <par_par_child1>
      <par_par__child1_child>XYZ</par_par__child1_child>
      ...
    </par_par_child1>
  </par_child2>
</parent>
```

And now

```
if <par_par__child1_child> = 'XYZ': 
  replace <child1> tag value to '123'
```

If in your opinion python is not the best for this task, what should I use? I will be very graceful for any help.

Comment: Do you mean adding an attribute like  `<child1 value="123">` ?

Comment: i'm still trying to change your example:) i want to change <child1>321</child1> to <child1>123</child1>

Comment: Test my edit, should work for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

After your clarification, working code using `lxml`:

```
from lxml import etree


xml = """<parent>
  <child1>321</child1>
  <par_child2>
    <par_par_child1>
      <par_par__child1_child>XYZ</par_par__child1_child>
      ...
    </par_par_child1>
  </par_child2>
</parent>"""

tree = etree.fromstring(xml)
for element in tree.iter('par_child2'):
    if element.find('par_par_child1/par_par__child1_child').text == 'XYZ':
        # Traverse up and back down again, I prefer this over indexes 
        element.find('../child1').text = '123'

print(etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True).decode('utf-8'))
```

Output

```html
<parent>
  <child1>123</child1>
  <par_child2>
    <par_par_child1>
      <par_par__child1_child>XYZ</par_par__child1_child>
      ...
    </par_par_child1>.
  </par_child2>
</parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for ppchild in root.iter('par_par_child1_child'):
    if ppchild.text == 'XYZ':
        ppchild.text = '123'
```

`root` is obtained by querying your tree: `tree.getroot()`

'XYZ' is the text of the `par_par_child1_child` element

Python is well suited to the task, but you have to learn it a bit before using it, even if it is easier than other languages.